# Need help writing bash script, how to take a pw as argument and automate its entry

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script to automate a gpg decryption process. The script takes a Password as one of its arguments. I need to find a way, when I run the gpg decryption within the script, the prompting for the password is automatically performed by the script.

Comment: Do you know which commands you can use to decrypt `gpg`? That's the main part of the script right there...

Answer (score 1):

I'd read the variable in using read (in silent mode so that the characters typed aren't visible), then use it.

Example:

```
echo -n "Enter password: "
read -s password
gpg ... --password=$password
```

Comment: Here is a sample of my script /n #!/bin/bash
# PGP Sample decryption script

echo "Positional Parameters"

OUTPUTFILE = $1
echo "Output file name is:" $1

ENCRYPTEDFILE = $2
echo "Encrypted file name is :" $2

PASSWORD = $3
echo "Password has been stored"

# Command to decrypt a selected file to a chosen source. PW needed to complete
gpg --output $1 --decrypt $2 

#System will prompt for a pw following this command, need script to enter PASSWORD
#This is where I need help

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying your script runs a program that requires a password to be typed in. To handle this, I have used [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). To start using expect while using bash, you must first type `expect -c`, and then include the rest of the expect part in single quotes. When an example of using expect is like this `expect 
{"passwordprompt:" {send "password\r"} }`
Where expect will by looking for the string "passwordprompt" and send the password when it reads that.

Comment: With his clarified question, you are entirely correct.  This is what `expect` was made for.

Comment: I think this is in the right direction. However, I only want the user to enter in the arguments at the beginning of the script. then after the gpg --output filename.txt --decrypt Encryptedfilename.txt.pgp when the system prompts the user for the password, have my script enter it for them. Thank you for the help!